# NSIS how to set finish to true

Tags: nsis

I want to make my installer to just quit after it did finish installation with out asking user to click "Finish". How can I set finish to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the instfiles page is the last page then it is controlled by the [AutocloseWindow](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#aautoclosewindow) property, you can also just call `Quit` in a section...

Comment: What does SetAutoClose = true does? I am trying it, building my my installer takes approximately 1 hour

Comment: The same thing, it changes the same internal flag. If you always want to close you should use the property. Use SetAutoClose if the installer should only close based on some condition...